# Another conjecture about couples of disjoint two-element sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $\{A_1,B_1\},\ldots,\{A_k,B_k\}$ be all the distinct unordered couples of subsets, with $A_i \cap B_i = \emptyset, 1 \le i \le k$, that can formed from a set $\{C_1,\ldots,C_q\}$, $q \le \binom{n}{2}$, of subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $2$, $A_i = \{a_{i,1},a_{i,2}\}, B_i = \{b_{i,1},b_{i,2}\}, 1 \le i \le k$.

Let $\mathcal{E}_j, 1 \le j \le n$ be the families of sets such that any set $E_j \in \mathcal{E}_j$ has the following properties:

1. $j \in E_j$
2. $a_{i,1} \in E_j \lor a_{i,2} \in E_j \iff b_{i,1} \in E_j \lor b_{i,2} \in E_j$

Let $f_j$ be the minimum size of a set in $\mathcal{E}_j$.

Finally define:

$$f = \max_{1 \le j \le n} f_j$$

I would like to prove that, for $3 \le m \le n-1$:

$$k \ge \frac{\binom{m+1}{2}\binom{m-1}{2}}{2} \implies f \ge m \tag{1}$$

And I am particularly interested in the case $m = \lceil n/2 \rceil$.

I think the conjecture is true if we assign to $\{A_1,B_1\},\ldots,\{A_k,B_k\}$ all the possible couples of disjoint subsets of size $2$ of $[m+1]=\{1,2,\ldots,m+1\}$, which are exactly $k=\frac{\binom{m+1}{2}\binom{m-1}{2}}{2}$, because, due to symmetry, we have $f_1 = f_2 = \cdots = f_{m+1}$, and we can use induction on $m$.

But how to prove it for a general choice of $\{C_1,\ldots,C_q\}$?

Motivation: this conjecture together with [this lower bound](https://mathoverflow.net/q/455668/136218), if both proved correct, could be used to prove the union-closed sets conjecture.

Comment: What is a point of $k$ being large, if the subsets may coincide?

Comment: @Ilyia Bogdanov the sets may coincide but not the couples. I have edited the question and I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I don't understand. If all the $A_i,B_i$ are pairwise disjoint, so $n=4k$, then don't we have $f=2$?

Comment: @domotorp for example if $n=4$ all the pairwise disjoint couples are $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, $\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$, $\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}$, i.e. $3 = \binom{3+1}{2}\binom{3-1}{2}/2$, because $4 = m+1$. If $1 \in E_1$ then $3 \in E_1$ or $4 \in E_1$ from the first couple, choose $3 \in E_1$, then from the second couple $2 \in E_1$ or $4 \in E_1$, choose $2 \in E_1$, then $E_1 = \{1,2,3\}$ and $f = f_1 = \vert E_1 \vert = m = 3$. Do you mean $A_i$ and $A_j$ also disjoint? Could you make an example?

Comment: Yes, I mean all are pairwise disjoint, that is why we have $n=4k$.

Comment: @domotorp yes in your example $f = 2$, but I don't see how this contradicts the conjecture.

Comment: Isn't the conjecture is that $f\ge m$, and $m$ can be arbitrarily large in my example?

Comment: You may take all  non-intersecting pairs $(A,B)$  where each of $A_i$ and $B_i$ intersects $[m-1]$. Here $k$ seems to be larger.

Comment: @domotorp yes now I understand, e.g. $n = 12$ gives $f \ge m = 3$, $n = 60$ gives $f \ge m = 4$. However, I made a big mistake in the question, because the couples should be all the possible couples generated from a set of them, in which case your construction isn't valid. I will update the question. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I have fixed the question with the missing important requirement about how the couples can be constructed.

Comment: If you take all couples, then there is no difference in the $f_j$. In fact, we are always in the example that you describe in the last but one para, no?

Comment: @domotorp no if we take all possible couples we have $f=f_1=\cdots=f_n=2k=n/2$. Take for example $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\{7,8\}\}$, couples will be $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, $\{\{1,2\},\{5,6\}\}$, $\{\{1,2\},\{7,8\}\}$, $\{\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$, $\{\{3,4\},\{7,8\}\}$, $\{\{5,6\},\{7,8\}\}$.

Comment: Why is there no $\{1,3\}$?

Comment: I was still at your original example with $n=4k$ and all disjoint pairs.